# Reading div content usig jQuery skips HTML, head and body tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am reading one HTML template and adding it to div (I have set runat='server') from server side code behind. This renders and shows HTML on page perfectly. Now I change the text within the rendered HTML on the client side and want to read updated text (complete HTML inside div) on the server side to update the template. So I have taken one hidden field and saving the updated HTML of div like this on the click of save button.

```
$('#btnSaveTemplate').click(function () {
            $('#UpdatedEmailTemplate').val($('#divEmailBody').html());
});
```

HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <strong><u>Database Decommission Notice – IMPORTANT NOTIFICATION</u></strong>
    </p>
    <p>
        <strong>FOLLOWING DATABASE(S) ARE SCHEDULED TO BE DECOMMISSIONED in 4 WEEKS from {SentDate};</strong>
    </p>
   
    <p>
        <strong>Why have you received this email?</strong>
    </p>
    <p>
        You are receiving this email as because you are an ITAO/ITAO delegate/CSM/CSM-1/key technical contact for database(s) that are scheduled to be decommissioned by 30. Below are the applications you have been identified.
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Issue is when I try to save changed html in the hidden field in the click on save, it gives me content like below. (this is the output of $('#divEmailBody').html() method)

```
\n\n\n    <title></title>\n\n\n    <p>\n        <strong>\n            <img style=\"width: 744px; height: 141px;\" alt=\"\" src=\"http://nyccgdbb0004.us.db.com/images/emailImmediateActionRequired.png\" border=\"0\">\n        </strong>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n        <strong><u>Database Decommission Notice – IMPORTANT NOTIFICATION</u></strong>\n    </p>\n    <p align=\"center\" class=\"MsoNormal\" style=\"margin: 0in 0.5in 6pt 0in; text-align: center;\">\n        <b>\n            <i>\n                <u>\n                    <span lang=\"EN-GB\" style=\"color: rgb(192, 0, 0); font-size: 14pt;\">Do not ignore this message</span>\n                </u>\n            </i>\n        </b>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n        <strong>FOLLOWING DATABASE(S) ARE SCHEDULED TO BE DECOMMISSIONED in 4 WEEKS from 1/23/2017;</strong>\n    </p>\n   \n    <p>\n        <strong>Why have you received this email?</strong>\n    </p>\n    <p>\n        <a title=\"\" class=\"editableText editable editable-pre-wrapped editable-click editable-unsaved\" href=\"#\" data-original-title=\"\" data-title=\"Update Text\" data-type=\"textarea\">You are receiving this email as because you are an ITAO/ITAO delegate/CSM/CSM-1/key technical contact for database(s) that are scheduled to be decommissioned by 30. Below are the applications you have been identified.test</a>\n    </p>\n\n\n\n"
```

How to read complete HTML?

Comment: Where is UpdatedEmailTemplate and divEmailBody in the DOM?

Comment: Your mistake is already at the point where you try and stuff a _complete_ HTML document into a div. That is of course invalid HTML, so the browser will discard elements it can’t make sense of in this context.

Answer (score 1):

If it is template then do not add it to any html element like div.. use script tag instead.

```
<script id="UpdatedEmailTemplate" type="text/x-template">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <strong><u>Database Decommission Notice – IMPORTANT NOTIFICATION</u></strong>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
</script>
```

if you append template to div it doesn't stay as is and browser do its own adjustment to make page a valid html. in a page you cant have two html tags so browser automatically removes other one. same for body. HTML never throws error but it fixes errors by its own.. sometime fixes are not same as what we want. that'ts why its imp to have valid html

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript

```
var html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
var text = '<html>' + html.innerHTML + '</html/>';
```

Using jQuery:

```
var text = '<html>' + $('html').html() + '</html/>';
```